# How do I implement a UIGestureRecognizer in my app in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Lets say I have an image of a tree and when I tap on the screen it changes to an image of a car how would I do this? This is the code I have so far but its not working. **(I have three images named "gp1", "gp2", and "gp3" and all of them have different number of taps to change the image.)**

I'm in Spritekit and using Swift.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

  //Create Touch
  createTouch()

}


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

  func createTouch() {

    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    gestureRecognizer2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    gestureRecognizer3.numberOfTapsRequired = 3

    gestureRecognizer == UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "gp2")
    gestureRecognizer2 == UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "gp3")
    gestureRecognizer3 == UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "gp1")

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mundi said, for each UIImageView, make sure userInteractionEnabled = true.  Otherwise, users won't be able to tap the image.  Then, create the gestureRecognizer. Set the action to the method that will handle the gesture.  Next, add the gestureRecognizer to the UIImageView.  Finally, write the method to handle the gesture.

```
@IBOutlet var gp1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var gp2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var gp3: UIImageView!

func createTouch() {
    // maker sure userInteractionEnabled is true
    gp1.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    gp2.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    gp3.userInteractionEnabled = true;

    // create the gesture recognizers
    let gestureRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapGesture:")
    let gestureRecognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapGesture:")
    let gestureRecognizer3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapGesture:")

    // set the number of taps
    gestureRecognizer1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    gestureRecognizer2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    gestureRecognizer3.numberOfTapsRequired = 3

    // add the gesture recognizer to the UIImageViews
    gp1.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer1)
    gp2.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer2)
    gp3.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer3)
}
```

Since these are all tap gestures, I've decided to use one method and a switch statement.  You could, however, create different methods for each gesture if you wanted to.

```
func tapGesture(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.numberOfTapsRequired {
    case 1:
        gp1.image = UIImage(named: "car")
    case 2:
        gp2.image = UIImage(named: "car")
    case 3:
        gp3.image = UIImage(named: "car")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the recognizer to the view and implement the action handlers `gp2` etc.

For `UIImageView` you should also make sure `userInteractionEnabled` is set to true.